# Is there a simple way to repeatedly call LSTM model instead of passing a sequence in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have a simple Keras model which is designed to be a bot for a game.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(144, activation='sigmoid'),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(144, return_sequences=True),
        tf.keras.layers.LSTM(3, activation='softmax')
    ])
```

Its input is the current situation in the game and output is a move to make. The model has LSTM layers inside of it cause it needs a short-term memory. The problem is that Keras LSTM are designed to take whole series of data as an argument, but in my case the next input depends on the previous output. Currently I am appending inputs to a list and calling model on it each step but it seems inefficient.

```
def __init__(self, model, loss_object, optimizer):
        #...
        self.model = model
        self.inputs = []

def __call__(self, encoded_input):
        encoded_input = encode(board, direction)
        self.inputs.append(encoded_input)
        input_data = np.array(self.inputs)
        input_data = tf.convert_to_tensor(input_data.reshape((1, input_data.shape[0], input_data.shape[1])))
        output = self.model(input_data)
```

Is there a simple way in Tensorflow 2.0 to call the model repeatedly and keep its short-term memory between calls instead of constructing a whole series of data?

Comment: To clarify your question before answering, you wish to have the data updated in 'real-time' to your LSTM, rather than having to re-run the model on a 'new' appended data set with the most recent result being appended?

Comment: Yes, I want to know is it possible by, for example, inheriting over an LSTM class?